# HTML - How to check an answer field if it has some specific words

Tags: html

I wan to make a webpage with some questions where you have to answer, for example there is this:

How many money do i earn?

The answer can be anything but it has to have "money" in his answer, for example

I earn 10 money.

How can i check the text that the user puts in the answer field and check if it has some specific words in it?
I hope you understand me and that you could help me.
If you don't understand, please ask me.

Comment: Are you comfortable using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript. more specifically you can match the string entered with something you provide using the match function.

```
var myString = "I earn money"; 
var matches = string.match(/money/g);
```

Returns an array with the matches... if a count of the array elements is greater than 0, you have a match.

[Javascript match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via PHP `preg_match(pattern, subject);`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
For example you can make HTML form, get value from it via `$_POST`, and then check for "money":

```
$value=$_POST['text'];
if (preg_match("/money/", $value)) {
//do something
}

echo <<<_END
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="text" value="$value" 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
_END;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.search()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) : input.value.search("money").

search returns the number of matches so you can just check input.value.search("money") > -1

while .match() returns an array of matches

Example:

in **HTML**

```
<head>
...
    include jquery library
...
</head>
...
<input name="answer" type="text"/>
```

in a .js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").change(function(){
        if($(this).val().search("money") >= 0) ... ok
        else...
    });
});
```